# Can this be solved with a template specialization, if not then how?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have several "resources" in my code base.  All of them are classes and share the same interface except one class, the ShaderProgram is different in just one way, it needs two strings for files names of the vertex and fragment files.

I have a template class called ResourceManager that handles all these resource except the shader one because it needs two files and the others need one, can I solve this with a template specialization?  It needs to be that ResourceManager sees GetOrLoadFromFile( string, string ) and not (string) versions, while the others have the opposite, they see (string) and not (string, string).  Also AttemptLoad needs the treatment too.  How can I make a solution for this please include code, I have never done template specializations before.

```
template < class ResType > class ResourceManager
{
public:
    ResourceManager(void);
    ~ResourceManager(void);

    SmartPointer<ResType> GetOrLoadFromFile( const std::string & fileName );

    //weak_ptr<ResType> GetResourceFromID( ResourceID & resID );

    void DestroyResources();
    void ReleaseResources();
    void ReloadResources();
protected:


private:
    SmartPointer<ResType> AttemptLoad( const std::string & fileName );

    std::unordered_map<string, SmartPointer<ResType> > mResMap;

};

// Relevant methods ( SNIPPED )
template < class ResType> SmartPointer<ResType>   ResourceManager<ResType>::GetOrLoadFromFile( const std::string & fileName )
    {
    if ( !mResMap.empty() )
        {
        auto index = mResMap.begin();
        auto end = mResMap.end();

        while ( index != end )
            {
            if ( index->first == fileName )
                {
                return index->second;
                }
            ++index;
            }
        }

    return AttemptLoad(fileName);
    }

template < class ResType > SmartPointer<ResType> ResourceManager<ResType>::AttemptLoad( const std::string & fileName )
    {
    SmartPointer<ResType> pRes( new ResType() );

    if ( pRes->LoadFromFile( fileName ) )
        {
        mResMap.insert( std::make_pair( fileName, pRes ) );
        return pRes;
        }
    else
        {
        LogFailure("Failed to load resource file " + fileName)
        return SmartPointer<ResType>(nullptr);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind templates is that you known your types before the execution times, i.e., at compilation time. If this is true, than what you are trying to do is an overloading using templates. So, bellow I just put a generic code, that you can adapt to your code, that do overloading at compilation time.

Note that, to avoid writing code twice, every common methods are put in base class and let to the derived class only the ones that diverges.

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
  // put common codes here
};

template <typename ResType>
class ResourceManager : public Base
{
public:
  unique_ptr<ResType> GetorLoad(const string &f) { cout << f << endl; return 0;}
};

// Specilizing class ResourceManager for string type
template <>
class ResourceManager<string> : public Base
{
public:
  unique_ptr<string> GetorLoad(const string &f1, const string &f2) {cout << f1 << f2 << endl; return 0;}
};

int main()
{
  ResourceManager<int> i;
  ResourceManager<string> s;

  i.GetorLoad("int");
  s.GetorLoad("string", "string");
}
```

PS. To compile and test this example, you need to use '--std=c++11' flag from gcc or clang++ compilers

Answer (score 1):

If both classes are under your control I would suggest a different solution. Why don't you change the AttempLoad method into something like

```
SmartPointer<ResType> AttemptLoad( const LoadConfiguration &p_loadConfiguration );
```

Where

```
class LoadConfiguration 
{
    public:
            std::string FirstFileName;
};
```

and

```
class ExtendedLoadConfiguration : public  LoadConfiguration 
{
    public:
            std::string SecondFileName;
};
```

you could then always work with LoadConfiguration and each AttemptLoad would be able to take what he needs. Adding new arguments will be easy, it's less code with the same signature and you wouldn't have to work with template specialization.

Comment: Wouldn't this make it possible to call ResourceManager<ShaderProgram>::AttempLoad( const LoadConfiguration ) Which is the single string class?  There isn't anything to prevent that in your example.

Comment: The idea is for AttempLoad to try to perform a dynamic_cast to the right type of LoadConfiguration. Yes, in a sense you are moving from compile time checks to run time checks. But in another sense, passing LoadConfiguration instead of ExtendedLoadConfiguration should be treated exactly like passing an empty second string - possible and should be handled easily. I think the benefits and comforts of a standard and extensible API are greater than this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement both 'GetOrLoadFromFile' functions:

```
#include <string>

struct R1 
{
  void load (const std::string &name) {}
};

struct R2 
{
  void load (const std::string &name0, const std::string name1) {}
};

template<typename R>
struct M
{
  R *get_or_load (const std::string &name)
  {
    R *p = new R();
    p->load (name);
    return p;
  }

  R *get_or_load (const std::string &name0, 
                  const std::string &name1)
  {
    R *p = new R();
    p->load (name0, name1);
    return p;
  }
};


M<R1> m1;

M<R2> m2;


int
main ()
{
  R1 *p0 = m1.get_or_load ("foo");
  // R1 *p1 = m2.get_or_load ("foo"); // error
  R2 *q0 = m2.get_or_load ("foo", "bar");
  // R2 *q1 = m1.get_or_load ("foo", "bar");  // error
}
```

The "wrong" member function will not be instantiated, unless actually there's a call to it, in which case the compiler will exit with diagnostics.